# Microsoft Excel application can not access the file "..."

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis-7

I don't what i dod uncorrect.
I did this steps:
To resolve this issue follow this steps

  Login to the server as a administrator.

Go to "Start" -> "Run" and enter "taskmgr"

Go to the process tab in task manager and check "Show Processes from all users"

If there are any "Excel.exe" entries on the list, right click on the entry and select "End Process"

Close task manager.

Go to "Start" -> "Run" and enter "services.msc"

Stop the service automating Excel if it is running.

Go to "Start" -> "Run" and enter "dcomcnfg"

This will bring up the component services window, expand out "Console Root" -> "Computers" -> "DCOM Config"

Find "Microsoft Excel Application" in the list of components.

Right click on the entry and select "Properties"

Go to the "Identity" tab on the properties dialog.

Select "The interactive user."

Click the "OK" button.

Switch to the services console

Start the service automating Excel

Test you applica

tion again.

But i get another error - about "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID".
I loked this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91?prof=required

But it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse my harsh answer, but your problem is that you use EXCEL in a server environment. It was never build to support that. Microsoft advises against it, because there are many unresolved problems.
It would be better (and more stable and orders of magnitude faster) to use a library like EPPLUS to manipulate the excel files.